# iOS library to send message to all users

Tags: ios, communication, messaging

Does anyone know of an iOS library that I can use to send a message to all users? From time to time I need to warn all users about new problems with iOS. Just wondering if there was a library for this.

Comment: Please elaborate. What do you mean by "all users"/what kind of software/etc.

Comment: _How_ do you want to notify your users? Popup in the app? Push notification? _Why_ do you want to notify your users? Would it not be better just to make your app work with new versions of the OS?

Comment: Stephen, it's so complicated. A 3rd party library is having problems and I need to warn users about it. OF COURSE the answer is to fix things, but I am not in control. I guess an alert. I was hoping to avoid push notification but maybe I need to do it. BTW it has to be compatible with iOS5 - or at least allow me to compile to iOS5

Comment: I was using GroundControl but due to changes with AFNetworking, I cannot use it and produce an IOS5 version of my app.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. It's so simple. Download a message file in the background and just display it.